# Getting specified Node values from XML document

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have a problem going through an XML document (with C#) and get all the necessary values. I successfully go through all specified XmlNodeLists in the XML document, successfully get all XmlNode values inside, but I have to get some values outside of this XmlNodeList.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Element xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost/AML/CaseInvestigationMangement/Moduli/XmlImportControls/xsdBorrow.xsd xsd2009027_kor21.xsd" Kod="370" xmlns="http://localhost/AML/CaseInvestigationMangement/Moduli/XmlImportControls/xsdBorrow.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ANode>
        <BNode>
            <CNode>
                <Example>
                    <Name>John</Name>
                    <NO>001</NO>
                </Example>
            </CNode>
        </BNode>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <Date>2011-10-01</Date>
    </ANode>
    <ANode>
        <BNode>
            <CNode>
                <Example>
                    <Name>Mike</Name>
                    <NO>002</NO>
                </Example>
            </CNode>
        </BNode>
        <ID>5678</ID>
        <Date>2011-03-31</Date>
    </ANode>
</Element>
```

This is the code that gets values for nodes Name and NO in every found ANode in the XML document:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString); //myXmlString is the xml file in string //copying xml to string: string myXmlString = xmldoc.OuterXml.ToString();
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Element[@*]/ANode/BNode/CNode");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  XmlNode example = xn.SelectSingleNode("Example");
    if (example != null)
    {
        string na = example["Name"].InnerText;
        string no = example["NO"].InnerText;
    }
}
```

Now I have a problem getting values for ID and Date.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just like you do for getting something from the `CNode` you also need to do for the `ANode`

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Element[@*]");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  XmlNode anode = xn.SelectSingleNode("ANode");
    if (anode!= null)
    {
        string id = anode["ID"].InnerText;
        string date = anode["Date"].InnerText;
        XmlNodeList CNodes = xn.SelectNodes("ANode/BNode/CNode");
        foreach (XmlNode node in CNodes)
        {
         XmlNode example = node.SelectSingleNode("Example");
         if (example != null)
         {
            string na = example["Name"].InnerText;
            string no = example["NO"].InnerText;
         }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I don't get any value. "anode" is null and got jump in line: "if (anode!= null)".

Comment: Also tried to remove the **ANode** from the first line. The first line should be `XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Element[@*]");`. In this case I got the values for **id** and **date**, but I got jump in line `foreach (XmlNode node in CNodes)`.

Comment: The loop is just in CNode. I tried `Console.WriteLine(id + " " + date + " " + na + " " + no);` in `if (example != null)` and I got:

**1234 2011-10-01 John 001**

and

**1234 2011-10-01 Mike 002**