# Select particular node value from XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have the following XML Document:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <appSettings>
  <Path> blahblahblah </Path> 
  <PathValue> blahblahblah </PathValue> 
  <domainName> blahblahblah </domainName> 
  <SuperUserEmail> blahblahblah </SuperUserEmail> 
  <SuperUserName> blahblahblah </SuperUserName> 
  <UserName> blahblahblah </UserName> 
  <Password> blahblahblah </Password>       
  <connectionstring>Data Source=ABC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mail;User ID=sa;Password=sa@</connectionstring> 
  </appSettings>
```

Now I have to extract the entire path from `connectionstring` node. I tried using the following code:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/appSettings/connectionstring");
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: can you share your error screen shots

Comment: i tried. It's not getting uploaded. On debugging it, all I'm getting is `System.XML.XMLelementlist`

Comment: see this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442024/getting-specified-node-values-from-xml-document" I hope this might be help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRY

```
XmlNode node = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/appSettings/connectionstring");

string nodeval=node.InnerText;
```