# How to extract every occurence of tags in an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML file:

```
<queryResponse xmlns="">
    <querySubjectResponse xmlns="">
        ...
        <report>
            <informationReported>
                <aar>
                    <narrative>THIS IS A TEST NARRATIVE</narrative>
                </aar>
            </informationReported>
            ...
            <statement>
                <subjectStatement>
                    <statement>THIS IS A TEST STATEMENT</statement>
                </subjectStatement>
            </statement>
            ...
        </report>
        ...
        <report>
            <informationReported>
                <aar>
                    <narrative>THIS IS A TEST NARRATIVE2</narrative>
                </aar>
            </informationReported>
            ...
            <statement>
                <subjectStatement>
                    <statement>THIS IS A TEST STATEMENT2</statement>
                </subjectStatement>
            </statement>
            ...
        </report>
        ...
        <report>
            <informationReported>
                <aar>
                    <narrative>THIS IS A TEST NARRATIVE3</narrative>
                </aar>
            </informationReported>
            ...
            <statement>
                <subjectStatement>
                    <statement>THIS IS A TEST STATEMENT3</statement>
                </subjectStatement>
            </statement>
            ...
        </report>
        ...
    </querySubjectResponse>
</queryResponse>
```

I was looking at LINQ to XML but am not sure how to implement it. I would like to save the narrative and for each narrative, save the statement into an array to be used later.

Example:

```
THIS IS A TEST NARRATIVE
THIS IS A TEST STATEMENT

THIS IS A TEST NARRATIVE2
THIS IS A TEST STATEMENT2

THIS IS A TEST NARRATIVE3
THIS IS A TEST STATEMENT3
```

How do I achieve it?

I am using `XDocument` to load the file:

```
XDocument X = XDocument.Load("myfile.xml");
var main = x.Element("queryResponse").Element("querySubjectResponse").Element("report").Element("informationReported").Element("aar");
```

I am trying to follow the answer from this link: [Linq to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491811/c-sharp-extracting-data-from-xml)

Comment: "*I would like to save the narrative and for each narrative, save the statement into an array to be used later.*" `<narrative>` doesn't contain a `<statement>`. Do you mean you want to save the `<statement>` in the `<report>` that contains the `<narrative>`? Also you have nested `<statement>`s, do you want to innermost one? The question is not clear and you do no show any attempt, besides that you load it in as an `XDocument`

Comment: I updated my question with what I would like to save and also I am able to get the elements and saved it to a `var` but not too sure how to proceed afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you presuming every report has a narrative and an optional statement:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
List<string> list = root.Descendants("report")
    .SelectMany(report =>
    {
        List<string> sub = new List<string>();
        sub.Add(report.Descendants("narrative").First().Value);
        string statement = (string)report.Descendants("statement")
                        .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Elements().Any() == false);
        sub.Add(statement ?? "NULL");
        return sub;
    })
    .ToList();
```

If you want the narratives and statements in separate list, do this instead:

```
var list = root.Descendants("report")
    .Select(report => new
    {
        Narrative = report.Descendants("narrative").First().Value,
        Statement = ((string)report.Descendants("statement")
                        .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Elements().Any() == false))
                    ?? "NULL"
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: For the second or the first option would it be possible to include the narrative and statement in different list?

Comment: also, for this code: `sub.Add(report.Descendants("statement")
                                            .Where(statement => statement.Elements().Any() == false)
                                            .First().Value);` I am getting `Sequence contains no elements` error.

Comment: @SiKni8 Then not every report contains a statement.

Comment: The third `statement` node is missing. Can I enter a NULL if it is missing and still be able to make it work? Also keep in mind there is child a `statement` inside a parent `statement`. I would like the child `statement`

Comment: Try with those changes.

Comment: @SiKni8 removed first code, so I wouldn't have to keep duplicating the work.

Comment: It might be too much to ask in this question but how do I now read or assign each Narrative/Statement?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks so much :)