# Extract data from a XML string using linq vs xmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have done the below many times using a xmlDocument approach, but I wanted to use the more powerful linq to xml approach.
However, I seem to have run into a wall.
I am getting data back from a restful API from twillio / crmText.
Here is a link to their site where their docs live:
http://crmtext.com/api/docs

Here is my XML string:

```
<response op="getcustomerinfo" status="200" message="ok" version="1.0">
  <customer>
    <totalMsg>3</totalMsg>
    <custId>9008281</custId>
    <custName></custName>
    <timestamp>2015-04-30 16:17:19</timestamp>
    <optinStatus>3</optinStatus>
    <custMobile>6185551212</custMobile>
    <subacct>1st Choice Courier</subacct>
  </customer>
</response>
```

I need to find out the optinStatus.  It should return 3.
I am using the below, which return the above xml

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(result1);
```

I have tried about 4000 different things, including:

```
 IEnumerable<XElement> otinStatus = from el in xdoc.Elements("customer") select el;
          IEnumerable<XElement> otinStatus2 = from el in xdoc.Elements("cusotmer.optinStatus") select el;
           IEnumerable<XElement> otinStatus3 = from el in xdoc.Elements("optinStatus") select el;
```

All of which returns no results.

Please help, I know this is something simple I am missing.
Thank you in advance -- Joe

Comment: Have you tried searching similar answers?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491811/c-sharp-extracting-data-from-xml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Retrieve an Element's Value

```
var status = xDoc
    .Descendants("optinStatus")    // get the optinStatus element
    .Single()                      // we're expecting a single result
    .Value;                        // get the XElement's value
```

## Example

Here is a working Fiddle for you. [You can see it running live here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LetUMZ). The output is `3`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        var status = xDoc.Descendants("optinStatus").Single();
        Console.WriteLine(status.Value);
    }

    private static string xmlString = @"

<response op=""getcustomerinfo"" status=""200"" message=""ok"" version=""1.0"">
  <customer>
    <totalMsg>3</totalMsg>
    <custId>9008281</custId>
    <custName></custName>
    <timestamp>2015-04-30 16:17:19</timestamp>
    <optinStatus>3</optinStatus>
    <custMobile>6185312349</custMobile>
    <subacct>1st Choice Courier</subacct>
  </customer>
</response> 

    ";
}
```

## Explanation

[`Descendents()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an instance axes method (or just *axes* in shorthand). It returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` of all matching descendents. On its results, we call [`Single()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It is a Linq method that returns the only element of a sequence. If there is more than one element, it throws an error. We're left with a single [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This represent an entire XML element. Since we only want its value not the entire element, we call the `Value` property. Bingo, we're done.

## A Bit More Detail

Axes come in two kinds:

- Instance axes methods, [which MSDN lists here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387099.aspx), are invokable members of the `XElement`, `XDocument`, and `XNode` classes.
- Extension axes methods, [which MSDN lists here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.extensions_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), are invokable on collections.

With one exception, an axes method returns a collection of type [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The exception is [`Element()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx), which returns the first matching child object. That what AmatuerDev used and, as in your question, if you are only expecting a single result, it is a just as good if not better approach that is `Descendants()`.

## Retrieve an Attribute Value

Once we have an `XElement`, we can retrieve one of its attributes instead of its value. We do that by calling the [`Attributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. It returns the matching [`XAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Since we only want the attribute value, we call the [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Voila.

```
// for attribute
var response = xDoc.Descendants("response").Single();
var attr = response.Attribute("status");
```

## General Approach

Using Linq to XML is a two step process.

1. Call an axes method to obtain an `IEnumerable<T>` result.
2. Use Linq to query that.

## See Also

Here is some relevant MSDN documentation:

- [How to: Retrieve the Value of an Element (LINQ to XML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx)
- [LINQ to XML Axes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387055.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming xDoc being the XDocument. Have you tried..

```
  var customer = xDoc.Root.Element("customer");
  var optinStatus = customer.Element("optinStatus");
  var optinStatusValue = optinStatus.Value;
```

Comment: var optinStatusValue = xdoc.Root.Element("customer").Element("optinStatus").Value;  I seriously did not realize that you could link Elements.  Your answer totally saved my butt.  Thank you.  Oh to have the past 2 hours back!  Joe