# Extract data from xml in c# getting NullReference

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am currently making my first steps in extracting data from an XML i get, where the following link provides the response I get: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=AT,%20Wien

Now I try to get the latitude and logitude of the first element:

```
 string serviceUri = string.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=AT,", location);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XDocument X = XDocument.Load(serviceUri);

        var position = X.Element("GeoCodeResponse").Element("result");
        var position1= position.Element("geometry").Element("location");
        string latitude = position1.Element("lat").Value;
        string longitude = position1.Element("lng").Value;
```

But it seems I missunderstood something from that question which was also answered here: [C# extracting data from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491811/c-sharp-extracting-data-from-xml)

Please help me understand it a little bit further,
br

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What line gets the null reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
var position = X.Root.Element("result");
```

if you debug your code in visual studio you will see that `X.Element("GeoCodeResponse")` returns null. And you are trying to use `X.Element("")` on null. You can also check null before accessing your root node.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple.

If you're splitting the statements like

```
var root = X.Element("GeoCodeResponse");
var position = root.Element("result");
```

You will see, that the NPE is thrown by

```
var position = root.Element("result");
```

If you're looking in debugmode what 'root' contains. You will see, that 'root' is 'null'. So there is no element 'GeoCodeResponse'.
It should be namend like 'GeocodeResponse' and you're solution works.