# Extract XML information by logging on to a website

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I am stuck at a place while working with a Windows Application.

> **I have to extract information from an XML file by logging on to a particular url with known credentials, where my XML file is present.**

I am unable to get how to access the real time information from web for a Windows Application?

Comment: can u give the link?

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific, don't you think? What application are you talking about? What did you try? Did it fail? Did you get error messages? Why did you not post your code?

Comment: string xml = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
after getting string xml, you can do manipulations you want

Comment: Sorry,I can't give the link.
I do have the administrator privileges for logging in but how to do it via code. @ValNolav

Comment: what is the question? can you download the xml file from url? or can you login successfully to the website or not? or deserialization of XML is the problem ?

Comment: i assume that by "logging on" you mean that you have some credentials you have to add to your request to reach the xml file - to do so have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for further reading how to work with credentials on requests.

Comment: @ValNolav Thankyou.It served the purpose.

Comment: @Matt Exactly Matt,this is what I meant.I have username & password to login to web page where i can find XML file.Now I have to extract child nodes attribute information from that XML file on basis of which I have to send E-mail notifications.

Answer (score 0):

according to the comments section, your path of success would look like this:

1. make yourself familiar with the WebClient class (as we already told you) by having a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) website
2. get to know how to convert the result from the web client into a so called XmlDocument (you can do a further reading on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442024/getting-specified-node-values-from-xml-document) SO question and answers) or have a look at the msdn developer network for some examples like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. put it all together, clap your hands three times and integrate the module into your existing project

in general: the [msdn developer network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us) gives you a nice basic idea of how things work in .NET as well as searching on SO for related questions. and for the next time: provide some code snippets or the core functions of "what's not working" so we can easily get a feeling of what you already tried or what might be gone wrong so far.

Answer (score -1):

You can download XML data from URL using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Then load it into **XDocument**.

Also [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) has Load method for direct XML loading by URI.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/25261435");
```