# Get data from a XML-Node by element-name

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, webclient

I´ve got a class called "`server`" with all attributes. I want to fill in the data from each node/element into the class.
The only way I know is foreach and than everytime a big switch-case. This can´t be the best way!

Here the XML-File:

```
<serverData  .....>
  <name>...</name>
  <number>...</number>
  <language>de</language>
  <timezone>...</timezone>
  <domain>...</domain>
  <version>...</version>
  ...
</serverData>
```

The XML-File is from an API and I get it with this lines:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(Request.request(URL));
```

And now I want do something like (no real code just an example):

```
Server server = new Server();
server.name = xmlDoc.node["name"].Value;
server.version = ...
...
```

Thank you for your solution.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442024/getting-specified-node-values-from-xml-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(Request.request(URL));

Server server = new Server {
    name = xDoc.Root.Element("name").Value,
    number = int.Parse(xDoc.Root.Element("name").Value),
    language = xDoc.Root.Element("language").Value,
    timezone = xDoc.Root.Element("timezone").Value
    /* etc. */
};
```

Since you have a well-formatted XML file with a constant structure, you can also simply serialize it using [**`XmlSerializer`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("serverData")]
public class ServerData
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("timezone")]
    public string Timezone { get; set; }

    /* ... */
}

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServerData));

using (Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString(Request.request(URL)))
{
    xmlSerializer.Deserialize(s);
}
```

`GenerateStreamFromString` implementation can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879395/how-to-generate-a-stream-from-a-string).

Comment: The first part of your answer helped me a lot. Thank you for this. The other answer is very well, too.