# Get element from xml node C#

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I have xml and I want to get the value of node . My XML looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdf:root xmlns:jdf="xxxxxxxx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<jdf:header>

    <jdf:locale-code>xx</jdf:locale-code>
    <jdf:country-code>xx</jdf:country-code>
</jdf:header>
<app:data xmlns:app="xxxxxx">
    <app:EventOut xmlns:ns2="xxxxxxx">
        <app:eventId>xxx</app:eventId>
        <app:distributorId>xxx</app:distributorId>
        <app:distributionNetworkId>xxx</app:distributionNetworkId>
        <app:typology>xxx</app:typology>
        <app:targets>
            <app:target>
                ......
            </app:target>
            <app:target>
                .....
            </app:target>
        </app:targets>
        <app:object>
            <ns2:internalEventObject>
                <ns2:id>!!!!!!!!</ns2:id>
                <ns2:lang1>xxx</ns2:lang1>
            </ns2:internalEventObject>
        </app:object>
        ...
    </app:EventOut>
</app:data>
```

I just try:

```
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(eventOutXml);

    var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");

    XmlNode anode = xml.SelectSingleNode("//ns2:id", nsmgr);
```

But it is not working.

In My XML I have few namespaces:jdf, app, ns2. Maybe I must add all these?

Comment: " it is not working."  How?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that the `ns2:` namespace prefix is not required in `SelectSingleNode`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting specified Node values from XML document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442024/getting-specified-node-values-from-xml-document)

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I try without "ns2" but is working the same. when I log "anode" the i get NULL

Comment: @roryapI get Null pointer exception

Comment: Can you make sure the ns2 namespace value is as same as what you used in your c# code?

Comment: @krolik1991 -- don't you think you should have included that information to start off with?  How could we possibly help you without that?

Comment: @krolik1991 are you sure `ns2` in the actual XML declared as such : `xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` ?

Comment: Yes, I have bad namespace added in C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml was missing end tag . And the namespace you added in the code was different in the xml. I did those two changes to the xml and was able to get this working.

Updated xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdf:root xmlns:jdf="xxxxxxxx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<jdf:header>
    <jdf:locale-code>xx</jdf:locale-code>
    <jdf:country-code>xx</jdf:country-code>
</jdf:header>
<app:data xmlns:app="xxxxxx">
    <app:EventOut xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <app:eventId>xxx</app:eventId>
        <app:distributorId>xxx</app:distributorId>
        <app:distributionNetworkId>xxx</app:distributionNetworkId>
        <app:typology>xxx</app:typology>
        <app:targets>
            <app:target>
                ......
            </app:target>
            <app:target>
                .....
            </app:target>
        </app:targets>
        <app:object>
            <ns2:internalEventObject>
                <ns2:id>!!!!!!!!</ns2:id>
                <ns2:lang1>xxx</ns2:lang1>
            </ns2:internalEventObject>
        </app:object>
        ...
    </app:EventOut>
</app:data>
</jdf:root>
```

After your code, just use this to get the value.

```
var value = anode.InnerText; //!!!!!!!!
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: I noticed the missing tag, I just assumed OP didn't copy the entire thing by accident. But hey that might be the whole root of the problem.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks! I had bad namespace added in c# code. Xml dont have end tag because it is no all of xml code.

Answer (score 1):

Write down the entire path for that node.

`XmlNode anode = xml.SelectSingleNode("/ns2:internalEventObjects/ns2:id", nsmgr);`