# Extract node from XML document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, nodes

I have this XML:

```
<WMFWUpload>
         <Date></Date>
         <GroupIndex></GroupIndex>
         <Id></Id>
         <NumGroups></NumGroups>
         <NumRecs></NumRecs>
         <Receipts>
            <Receipt>
               <CreationDateTimeStamp></CreationDateTimeStamp>
               <CreationProcessStamp></CreationProcessStamp>
               <DateTimeStamp></DateTimeStamp>
               <InterfaceRecordId />
               <ProcessStamp></ProcessStamp>
               <UserStamp></UserStamp>
            </Receipt>
         </Receipts>
</WMFWUpload>
```

I read the document from a path and I want to select only the Recepit Node, but not only the values also the nodes, and the result should be:

```
<Receipt>
    <CreationDateTimeStamp></CreationDateTimeStamp>
    <CreationProcessStamp></CreationProcessStamp>
    <DateTimeStamp></DateTimeStamp>
    <InterfaceRecordId />
    <ProcessStamp></ProcessStamp>
    <UserStamp></UserStamp>
</Receipt>
```

This is my code so far, I'm stuck.

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Pite\Selmec\WorkingData\Origen\ReceivingUpload.xml");
            var query = from c in doc.Descendants("Receipt").DescendantsAndSelf().ToList() select c;

            foreach (var value in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting specified Node values from XML document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442024/getting-specified-node-values-from-xml-document)

Comment: That code is diferent I want  all my output in a string value. they select some values

Comment: okey, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
var query = doc.Descendants("Receipt");
string s = string.Concat(query);
```

**Update**

Make sure to have this line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` on top of your xml file

I have used this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WMFWUpload>
         <Date></Date>
         <GroupIndex></GroupIndex>
         <Id></Id>
         <NumGroups></NumGroups>
         <NumRecs></NumRecs>
         <Receipts>
            <Receipt>
               <CreationDateTimeStamp></CreationDateTimeStamp>
               <CreationProcessStamp></CreationProcessStamp>
               <DateTimeStamp></DateTimeStamp>
               <InterfaceRecordId />
               <ProcessStamp></ProcessStamp>
               <UserStamp></UserStamp>
            </Receipt>
         </Receipts>
</WMFWUpload>
```

Comment: Which is the same as just `doc.Descendants("Receipt")`.

Comment: I didit already, but I dont recieve a string or anything I'm missing something, beacuase the result is System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.Xml.Linq.XElement]

Comment: so you want all as a string ?

Comment: @Danielopez.. does it help ?

Comment: @Mostafiz it doesnt, the value in 's' is empty

Comment: does your xml have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` line at the begining ? because its working for me

Comment: @Mostafiz it works with the code above but actually its a file bigger and with namespaces, I dont know if this afects the code